# Run an X11 program under Cygwin

Tags: x11, environment-variables, cygwin, display

How do I set the appropriate DISPLAY environment variable?

I try to launch idle in cygwin using the following command:

```
idle
```

...and I get a display error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Then I try the following:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

...And of course it says it `couldn't connect to display ":0.0"

How do I find which display variable is appropriate to launch a certain application?

Answer (score 2):

You most likely haven't started the [cygwin/X](http://x.cygwin.com/) server, or maybe not even installed it, you should do that first, so that there is an actual X Display to connect to. 
cygwin normally only handles commandline programs and the idle development invorment for Python is X based

Alternatively you can use the Windows idle environment for development and run the programs under cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

I got "idle3" to run.  It is NOT a stand-alone and needs an X-Window already running and present on your Windows environment.

I ran "xwin" first.  xwin creates the display that "export DISPLAY=:0.0" resolves to.